# Why do I get a Bad Request with this jQuery post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this JavaScript that executes when the commit button for a form is clicked. It is supposed to submit the form body and a file:

```
$("#submitButton").off("click").on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var url = "/portal/ProjectAuthority/Boq" + "?projectId=" + "0831260e-7018-dd49-9a84-daaf442bc1ec";

    debugger;
    var data = new FormData();

    //Form data
    var formData = $('#BoqReviewForm').serializeArray();
    $.each(formData, function (key, input) {
        data.append(input.name, input.value);
    });

    //File data
    var fileData = $('input[name="boqFile"]')[0].files;
    for (var i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {
        data.append("boqFile", fileData[i]);
    }

    $("#boqDataWrapper").empty();
    $.post({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (resp) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                getBoqReviewData(resp.importId);
            },
            100);
        },
        error: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The `url` is:

```
http://localhost/portal/ProjectAuthority/Boq?projectId=0831260e-7018-dd49-9a84-daaf442bc1ec
```

and the action method signature is:

```
public ActionResult Boq(Guid projectId, BoqUploadViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase boqFile)
```

When I click the submit button, the jQuery Ajax `error` function is invoked before my breakpoint at the beginning of the action method, so the action method itself is not returning `Bad Request`, whatever tries to invoke the action method is.

Is there any obvious reason for the `Bad Request` error?

Comment: Is `input[name="boqFile"]` inside `#BoqReviewForm`?  Just guessing, but would it attempt to serialise in the form.serializeArray()?  Try moving it outside the form (as a test)

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong. But I think you do not need parameter `model and boqFile` in `c# action` when you send data as `formdata`. you can receive data later like below and `Deserialize` to a model if needed. `var boqFile= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["boqFile"];` this one for file and below for model data `var YourModel= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["YourModel"];
                    var model= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(YourModel);`

Comment: @freedomn-m Tried that, thanks, but I still get a Bad Request.

Comment: @NagibMahfuz Thanks, but once I got this working again, it works fine with my action method params just as they are.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the viewmodel property for `boqFile` has a homemade data annotation attribute that is supposed to validate file extensions, e.g. to only `xlsx`, and that attribute was constantly failing, causing a bad request because the ajax call didn't return the model with errors.

I found this by skipping the ajax call and doing a straight postback, and then I got an error about the file extension, which was correct. I removed the faulty attribute, and the postback returned the valid json intended for the ajax call. Then I just went back to the ajax call and all is working.